# Sharepoint db issue after DB move to SQL 08

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, wss-3.0

Recently we have moved our sharepoint 2007 db from sql 2000 server to 2008 x64 SQL server.
All seems well, however there is a problem where the sql server stops running and the service has to be restarted.
The errors mention insufficient internal memory etc.
I have tried to start the db using -g384 which is the default in sql 2000 but 256 is default for 2008 I believe.
This has not rectified the issue.
I was advised that perhaps the issue may be rectified by upgrading to wss 3.0 sp2 however When I have tried to install this i get another error post sp2 update and have to refer back to a vm snapshot.
The error after the service pack is Server error: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=96177
So I guess I have a few questions How can I fix the first issue and the 2nd issue.
I have checked out many forums and posts and have tried a few things and still get no joy.
Any assistance would be great.

UPDATE
I have fixed the Server error: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=96177 the i needed to run the wss sp2 as well as the office servers sp2 then the config wizard then the moss configuration worked. The errors I am getting in SQL are

SQL Server was unable to run a new system task, either because there is insufficient memory or the number of configured sessions exceeds the maximum allowed in the server. Verify that the server has adequate memory. Use sp_configure with option 'user connections' to check the maximum number of user connections allowed. Use sys.dm_exec_sessions to check the current number of sessions, including user processes.

A read operation on a large object failed while sending data to the client. A common cause for this is if the application is running in READ UNCOMMITED isolation level. The connection will be terminated.

There is insufficient system memory in resource pool 'internal' to run this query.

These errors are by a user that was created as a service for sharepoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that The server was using all of its 4GB of RAM just before the SQL server service stopped.
So I shut it down (it is virtual) added 4 GB of RAM to total 8GB. 
It has been running for 2 days now and not an error in the log.(touch wood)
But I did notice that the serve did reach 4gb of RAM during the time that the outage usually occured.

So I continue to monitor and post results.

This has not fixed the problem.  When I gave it 8 GB sql just used 8GB.

I dont know what else to try. 
Time for a SQL guru I think

Comment: Still running after increasing RAM...will monitor for a few more days.

Comment: I had to change max amount of memory from 214xxxx to 6155MB. Since I changed this I have not had a crash yet. It has been 5 days. Still monitoring

Comment: This server has been running for over a weeks without issue since the change above. Very happy.

Answer (score 0):

What is the specific error message that you get in the SQL ErrorLog when it crashs and shuts down?

How much memory is in the server?  How much memory is SQL configured for?  How large are the databases?  How many sharepoint users are their?

Comment: SQL server has 4GB ram but it isnt breaking a sweat. See edit above for error messages databases are only a few hundred MB.  There are approx 1000 sharepoint users.

Comment: Based on the error message it sounds like the SQL Server is running out of available process memory.  How much memory is allocated to the SQL Server?  You can check this with sp_configure.  What's the User Connections number set to (referenced in the error you posted)?

Comment: 32767 is "user options" max.  Config_value is 0

Comment: I had to change max amount of memory from 214xxxx to 6155MB. Since I changed this I have not had a crash yet.  It has been 5 days. Still monitoring

Comment: A max memory setting of 6155MB is effectively the same as leaving it at the default.  You should set it to somewhere around 3072 which will leave 1 Gig of memory for the OS and 3 Gigs for the SQL Server.

Comment: But the server has 8GB of RAM so it leaves 1.5GB for the OS and 6.5GB for SQL.
I dont know why it worked but it did.

Comment: Oh, I thought the server had 4 Gigs installed.  6.5 would be an excellent setting.

Answer (score 0):

Can you login using the Dedicated Admin Connection (backdoor method for connections to a hung/non-responsive server - use SQLCMD -A) when it happens again and see how many connections there are?

Use the following T-SQL:

```
SELECT loginame, count (*) AS Connections
FROM master.dbo.sysprocesses (nolock)
GROUP BY loginame
ORDER BY loginame;
GO
```

You probably also want to call Product Support to help out quicker than this forum.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server will use all available memory unless you limit it. Set the maximum server memory from the server's properties.

Answer (score -1):

Is the IIS server leaking memory as well, or only the SQL server machine?  Is the SQL service death dependent on SP usage?

Comment: the service death seems to happen at around 7pm which is very low traffic time.

Comment: No prob with IIS just SP. It is just the SQL server service and the SQL agent service that just stop. When they do all DB connections are lost